# get detail error from LegacyJavaScriptObject in JS Dart

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, web3js

I'm working on web3 wrapper with Flutter

I have a class to manage interaction between dart en js

```
@JS()
library webthree.internal.js;

import 'dart:html';

import 'package:js/js.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

import 'dart_wrappers.dart';

@JS('ethereum')
external Ethereum? get _ethereum;

/// Extension to load obtain the `ethereum` window property injected by
/// Ethereum browser plugins.
extension GetEthereum on Window {
  /// Loads the ethereum instance provided by the browser.
  ///
  /// For more information on how to use this object with the webthree package,
  /// see the methods on [DartEthereum].
  Ethereum? get ethereum => _ethereum;
}

@JS()
class Ethereum {
  external bool get isMetaMask;
  external int get chainId;
  external bool autoRefreshOnNetworkChange;
  external bool isConnected();

  /// This should not be used in user code. Use `stream(event)` instead.
  @internal
  external void on(String event, Function callback);

  /// This should not be used in user code. Use `stream(event)` instead.
  @internal
  external void removeListener(String event, Function callback);

  /// This should not be used in user code. Use `requestRaw` instead.
  @internal
  external Object request(RequestArguments args);
}

@JS()
@anonymous
@internal
class RequestArguments {
  external String get method;
  external Object? get params;

  external factory RequestArguments({required String method, Object? params});
}
```

The communication in RPC works with this code in a extension `extension DartEthereum on Ethereum`:

```
  /// Sends a raw rpc request using the injected Ethereum client.
  ///
  /// If possible, prefer using [asRpcService] to construct a high-level client
  /// instead.
  ///
  /// See also:
  ///  - the rpc documentation under https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html
  Future<dynamic> rawRequest(String method, {Object? params}) {
    // No, this can't be simplified. Metamask wants `params` to be undefined.
    final args = params == null
        ? RequestArguments(method: method)
        : RequestArguments(method: method, params: params);
    return promiseToFuture(request(args));
  }
```

The issue is when the exception would come through, it would be an instance of LegacyJavaScriptObject and this error contains no info..
And my need is to get error content.

I read on https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/52572 it will be better to manage  custom errors can be interoperable with @staticInterop

But i don't know how to update Ethereum extension to do that...

Any idea to manage this ?

NB: This code comes from `web3dart` and `webthree` Dart libs